# Ruby on Rails always pointing local redis Server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, redis, redis-objects

I am using [Redis](http://redis.io/) with my [ruby on rails application](https://github.com/diatmpravin/rails-redis-demo.git), To map Ruby object with Redis using [redis-objects](https://github.com/nateware/redis-objects), [dm-core](https://rubygems.org/gems/dm-core) and [dm-redis-adapter](https://rubygems.org/gems/dm-redis-adapter). Below are the code snipts

Gemfile

```
gem 'redis-objects'
gem "dm-core", "~> 1.2.1"
gem "dm-redis-adapter"
```

/config/initializers/redis.rb

```
// LOCAL REDIS SERVER
Redis.current = Redis.new(:host => '127.0.0.1', :port => 6379)
// REMOTE REDIS SERVER
#Redis.current = Redis.new(:host => '<VM IP>', :port => <VM PORT>, :password => '<PASSWORD>')
```

Model.rb

```
DataMapper.setup(:default, {:adapter  => "redis"})

class User
  include Redis::Objects
  include DataMapper::Resource

  include ActiveModel::Validations  
  include ActiveModel::Conversion  

  # datamapper fields, just used for .create
  property :id, Serial
  property :name, String
  property :email, String
  property :des, Text

  def id
    1
  end

end

User.finalize
```

It's working fine for local redis server. Why app always pointing local redis, Even when providing remote host and port?

**SOLVED: checkout my answer.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per Question:

```
// LOCAL REDIS SERVER
Redis.current = Redis.new(:host => '127.0.0.1', :port => 6379)
// REMOTE REDIS SERVER
#Redis.current = Redis.new(:host => '<VM IP>', :port => <VM PORT>, :password => '<PASSWORD>')
```

Model.rb

```
 DataMapper.setup(:default, {:adapter  => "redis"})
```

In above code, I am overloading Redis configuration in User model.
In that case, I need to write remote configuration in model as well.

```
DataMapper.setup(:default, {:adapter  => "redis", :host => '<VM IP>', :port => <VM PORT>, :password => '<PASSWORD>'})
```

Answer (score 1):

Redis.current is a method which always gives a new connection if the instance variable @current is empty.  See https://github.com/redis/redis-rb/blob/master/lib/redis.rb#L19

```
  def self.current
    @current ||= Redis.new
  end
```

Try assigning Redis.new to some other global like $redis.  This should mostly fix your issue.

Comment: I am not using redis-rb

Comment: I think redis-objects uses redis-rb internally. see https://github.com/nateware/redis-objects/blob/master/redis-objects.gemspec

Comment: Solved, checkout my answer.